# OverQuotaException for billing enabled Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine

Earlier today a service call in my Google App Engine app stopped working, returning the following error:

500 Server Error

## Error: Server Error

### The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please [report](http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html) your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

HTML code:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>If the problem persists, please <A HREF="http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html">report</A> your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

I checked the [GAE system status](https://code.google.com/status/appengine/) and found Memcache had the status of "investigating". Now later in the day, all system statuses are normal, but I'm getting an `OverQuotaException` from my service call now:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:491)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:392)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:781)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:823)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:808)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:902)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:807)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1110)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:950)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2335)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2137)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2100(RpcNetChannel.java:150)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3214)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:614)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:405)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ClientAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:425)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:266)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.readPackets(UdrpcTransport.java:218)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$1.run(UdrpcTransport.java:82)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:578)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1002)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:136)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1855)
```

Under Quota Details in the GAE dashboard all of the resources are under quota, with "Okay" in the rate column. I have billing enabled on the app as well, even if it were over quota I shouldn't be receiving this error. What is the problem here? I'm not even calling a `Put()` method in this service call. I'm only querying data.

**UPDATE:** As the next reset of my quotas is drawing close with 0 hours remaining (probably midnight pacific time in 20 minutes), still no actual exceeding of any quota either, I do get this new error:

503 Over Quota

**Error**

> ## Over Quota
>
> This application is temporarily over its serving quota.  Please try again later.

HTML code:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>503 Over Quota</title>
<style><!--
body {font-family: arial,sans-serif}
div.nav {margin-top: 1ex}
div.nav A {font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial,sans-serif}
span.nav {font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold}
div.nav A,span.big {font-size: 12pt; color: #0000cc}
div.nav A {font-size: 10pt; color: black}
A.l:link {color: #6f6f6f}
A.u:link {color: green}
//--></style>

</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<table border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 width=100%>
<tr><td bgcolor=#3366cc><font face=arial,sans-serif color=#ffffff><b>Error</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<blockquote>
<H1>Over Quota</H1>
This application is temporarily over its serving quota.  Please try again later.

<p>
</blockquote>
<table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><td bgcolor=#3366cc><img alt="" width=1 height=4></td></tr></table>
</body></html>
```

This error now comes up when I do anything in the app, the HTML code popping up in a dialog box.

**UPDATE 2:** My quota just reset and my app is functioning normally again. But this doesn't answer my question as to why this occurred in the first place. Luckily I am still developing the app and I was the only one inconvenienced by this server glitch. What am I to do in these situations to get my server back online? Is this a common occurrence? Is there some way to receive an email notification if the server is throwing errors and my app is not functioning? Obviously waiting 24 hours for the server to reset is not a valid solution.

Comment: there's no need to put the source of the error message really, it's generic.

Comment: I just included the source mostly for anyone else receiving the same error to be able to find it. Since full HTML code isn't allowed in the question, it preserves the full error received. Also, the fact that it kept changing and I can't get back the previous errors, they're saved.

Comment: It's true as you said.. `Obviously waiting 24 hours for the server to reset is not a valid solution.`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's possible that your application is designed in such a way that if it's initial memcache query fails then it hits the datastore over and over again. Or having failed to set a value in memcache it never tries again, assuming it's there. Why that does not show in the logs I do not know (you are looking at the expanded quota logs, not the summary right?)

They recommend that you design in failure points, so if for example the datastore is unavailable your app does not crash rather it returns a sensible message to the user. Likewise backends - they are supposed to run 24/7 but you still have to build in shutdown code just in case the instance needs to close (and you get told in advance!).

I doubt your question (why did this happen) is answerable in it's current form however.

Comment: I was looking at https://appengine.google.com/dashboard/quotadetails. I don't know where the expanded logs you're referring to are if this is not them. Also, please explain how an app that has billing enabled could ever be over quota. The purpose of billing is so that any resource that goes over quota will be charged for.

Comment: yes, that's the one. rather then the one you see under dashboard. I understand that paid apps can still potentially be over quota as there are some "safety" limits in the system (per second limits etc that can't be overridden). but TBH I was not thinking in terms of billing enabled there.